# Match object's 3D rotation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm new to opencv, but willing to learn. I'm wondering if something described below is possible.

Camera sees a white pencil (tube, cylinder etc.) on a dark background. I want to extract object's rotation in 3D space and use it in my program. It doesn't have to be very accurate or fast (even ~10fps will do).

I'm obviously looking for a solution, but for some guidance: what to look at, what to read, how is this procedure called by professionals.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to extract 3D rotation from one image of arbitrary object because geometrical ambiguities. You can get the same image whith different coordinates/orientations of object. But you can extract angle of rotation in screen image plane. 
You can use moments to solve this problem. First you should binarize image. You can made it using some color filtering teqnique. When you have binarized image, you can evaluate moments http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html. When you done you can compute angle as below:

```
...
    double M00=moments.m00;
    double M20=moments.m20;
    double M02=moments.m02;
    double M11=moments.m11;
    // Center of mass
    double xc=M10/M00;
    double yc=M01/M00;        

    double A=(M20/M00)-xc*xc;
    double B=2*((M11/M00)-xc*yc);
    double C=(M02/M00)-yc*yc;
    // Ellipse axis
    double LL=sqrt( ( (A+C)+sqrt(B*B+(A-C)*(A-C)) )/2)*2;
    double LW=sqrt( ( (A+C)-sqrt(B*B+(A-C)*(A-C)) )/2)*2;

    // 
    M20=moments.mu20;
    M02=moments.mu02;
    M11=moments.mu11;

    double theta=(atan2(2*M11,(M02-M20))/2)*(180/M_PI);
...
```

There is way to estimate 3D rotation, if you use flat object with known size. You can estimate homography matrix. And the decompose it to rotation and translation. For example as it described here: http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/17/47/39/PDF/RR-6303.pdf .